# redirect ajax request to sfDoctrineGuard login on session timeout symfony 1.4

Tags: ajax, redirect, symfony-1.4

so I had this issue for ages.
When the session times out and the user then makes an ajax call the page doesn't redirect to the sfDoctrineGuard login page.

I was really surprised that this wasn't addressed many times but I really struggled to find a good solution, some involved sending back headers and picking up in ajax call but that seemed overkill.

Solution posted below but suggestions for improvements welcome.
Anyone more knowldegable about javascript may point out flaws in this perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

By placing this:

```
if ($sf_request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href='".$sf_request->getUri()."'</script>";
exit();
}
```

at the top of the sfGuard signinSuccess.php template the page is redirected outside of the ajax call.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable and fairly easy solution. Another one would be to check if the AJAX request returned a 401 and if yes show a login dialog which will enable the user to login with AJAX and will avoid the page reload.

Comment: How would you go about showing the dialogue given that this is currently covering any ajax call. Some generic javascript function included in all pages that is called by this bit of javascript above? - can you 'break out' of an ajax call like this?

Comment: You don't have to break anything ;) In fact the jQuery `ajax()` function accepts a callback for different responses: `statusCode: {401: function() { ... }}`. You can add a function there which will show the login form. You will still need to think of a way how to automatically send the original request again after the user logs in (unless you don't want to do that).

Comment: much delayed reply, this was very helpful comment about thr callback option in jquery ajax function.